# Best way to create relationship between multiple tables

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have a question about how to best handle a table that would be shared among multiple relationships, but shouldn't really be joined with all these tables.  For example, suppose I have a table that has US States in it.  Then, in this example, I have maybe three or four other tables that have a relationship with the States table, like:  a Users table (where the user is from), a Car registration table, an Email table (maybe on this system we track sent and received emails and where they originate from) and some other table.  If I joined all of these tables to the State table, it kind of makes it look like all of these table should have some sort of relationship with one-another.  Maybe this is so for a few tables (Like User and Car registration) but not necessarily between all the tables (User and Email table for example).  Or another example might be that we have two tables, Employees and Work_Office.  Each has there own state.  And each is joined to one-another, creating a loop (Work_Office has many Employees.  Employee belongs to State and Work_Office belongs to State).  Now we have a loop.

So, is it better to have multiple "State" tables?  It doesn't seem like it would be.  But at the same time, I don't want to create relationships that might not really exist?  Or is it better to just have the tables but not actually create any sort of relationship?

Thanks
jason

Comment: I think this would be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com … after all, it's not really a programming problem, but rather a database architecture related one.

Comment: @lxg - `database-design` is a tag with 1.7K followers and 14K questions.  Not every question on SO is about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is absolutely *worse* to have multiple STATE tables.
2. There is nothing wrong with many tables referencing one specific table For example, it is nothing wrong with Users and Work_Office and Car_Registration tables referencing to an Address table.
3. However, there are a few things that you should note:

   - State vs. Address:
     Do Employees, and Work_Office and other tables that reference State table also reference other Address related tables (like City)? If yes, then you should consider having an Address table that references the Street table and the  City table and the State table and has a field containing the rest of the address, like the house number. Now, all the entities that has an address should only reference this address table.
   - Employee and Users and Email: only one of these should reference the Address table, the rest should reference each other. That is, the Employee should reference the Users table and the Users table should contain an  email column, or reference the Email table

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I knew the multiple table consideration was wrong but wasn't really sure how else to go about this.